# Is it easy to transfer a domain name out of Network Solutions?

Tags: domain-registrar, domain-transfer

I registered some domains years ago with Network Solutions and, from my experience, agree with all the complaints about their "services. Googling around, I see that getting a domain name out their clutches can include "an exorbitant amount of hoops to jump through".

Anybody ever succeeded in transferring a domain name from NS?

Answer (score 1):

The domain registrar has nothing to do with it and can't stop transfers out.

If you have domain privacy disabled, the domain is unlocked and you have the EPP code, submit a transfer through your new registrar.

You will receive a confirmation email that needs to be clicked through to keep the process moving.

https://archive.icann.org/en/transfers/policy-12jul04.htm

Comment: Sounds easy - but if you read the third comment on the link in my question (Mark of Aurora, July 19, 2015), it doesn't always work out like that.

Comment: Then make a complaint to ICANN

Comment: So my question should be: "How come ICANN has never done anything to stop Network Solutions' outageous business practices?" ...Might try it, at the risk of being off-topic.

Comment: done: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84610/why-has-icann-not-stopped-network-solutions-outrageous-business-practices